# What is the Oracle Cloud shell password for default user

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-shell

sometime we need to play in role of superuser like `su` or `sudo`, what is the Oracle Cloud Shell password for default account?

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, although it is expressed as down vote, I should have gone to `serverFault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have that. Use SSH with the private key and just sudo. Are you using OCI with Oracle Linux distribution?

**EDIT**: sorry, misread the issue. You can't 'su' in Oracle Cloud Shell. What do you need to 'su' for?

If you need more advanced features I would advise create a small (e.g. micro) instance, doing your stuff, and shutting down when not used anymore (you won't be charged when the instance is stopped).

Comment: I guess you don't get what is Oracle Cloud Shell. It is not the typical OCI compute instance.

Comment: Thanks, previously what I need `su` help is to install software in system level. Now I know that all these software pack installed outside of user home will not be persistent after cloud shell restart. So I did it in vain and consequentially, no need to struggle `sudo` problem.