# Can not deploy Go in Oracle Cloud Function using Cloud Shell

Tags: function, go, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-functions, oracle-cloud-shell

I tried to  Creating and Deploying Oracle Cloud Functions by following the [official documentation instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Functions/Tasks/functionsuploading.htm). I can create and deploy using java runtime but when I deploy go runtime always return error.

I tried to init Go function using this command in Oracle Cloud Shell:

```
fn init --runtime go hello-go
```

then I tried to deploy it

```
fn -v deploy --app test
```

but it returned error like below:

```
Deploying hello-go to app: test
Bumped to version 0.0.7
Building image bom.ocir.io/bmptwl2psusa/repo/hello-go:0.0.7 
FN_REGISTRY:  bom.ocir.io/bmptwl2psusa/repo
Current Context:  ap-mumbai-1
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/10 : FROM fnproject/go:dev as build-stage
 ---> 96c8fb94a8e1
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /function
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8961dd299ec1
Step 3/10 : WORKDIR /go/src/func/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5a4c2c6e13f1
Step 4/10 : ENV GO111MODULE=on
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 22022ff2fcf8
Step 5/10 : COPY . .
 ---> 714622a6ff03
Step 6/10 : RUN cd /go/src/func/ && go build -o func
 ---> Running in 39fedbc476f4
build func: cannot find module for path github.com/fnproject/fdk-go
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /go/src/func/ && go build -o func' returned a non-zero code: 1


Fn: error running docker build: exit status 1
```

When I'm using java runtime with `fn init --runtime java hello-java` command, it's successfully deployed, Why always fail when using go?

I tried to run `go build -o func` in `hello-go` directory but it's returned:

```
go: finding module for package github.com/fnproject/fdk-go
go: writing stat cache: mkdir /usr/share/gocode/pkg: permission denied
go: downloading github.com/fnproject/fdk-go v0.0.3
func.go:10:2: mkdir /usr/share/gocode/pkg: permission denied
```

I know it happened because `/usr/share/gocode/` directory is under root user, but I dont know how to change the permission on that folder because Oracle Cloud Shell can not use root user or sudo. (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611378/what-is-the-oracle-cloud-shell-password-for-default-user))

Maybe I can do it if I use real VM shell or local shell/terminal, but I want to use Oracle Cloud Shell because I just followed official instructions that suggested me using Oracle Cloud Shell, so how to deploy Oracle Cloud Functions with Go runtime using Oracle Cloud Shell?

Mostly the official documentations only give the examples using Java runtime, that make me paranoid when using go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in cloudshell that we are figuring out the best way to solve.

As a short-term workaround you can do this once:

```
mkdir ${HOME}/gopath
```

Then set this in your terminal:

```
export GOPATH=${HOME}/gopath
```

You should probably edit your ~/.bashrc to set the GOPATH variable automatically so you don't forget